# Ubuntu mount cifs from terminal, error: mount: can't find /home/socio/spc in /etc/fstab

Tags: 16.04, mount, samba, cifs

I try to mount a smb share in ubuntu from command line.
This is one-time mount, I do not want to alter fstab or reboot the machine.

The command used is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19942306/4687565) answer:

```
udo mount -t cifs //<server>/<share> -o username=user@domain,unc=\\\\<server>\\<share> /home/<user>/spc
```

It prints an error instead:

```
can't find /home/<user>/spc in /etc/fstab
```

What is that supposed to mean?
And how do I get it to work?

Comment: try to replace all occurences of <server>, <share> and <user> with real values.

Comment: Obviously, they were replaced by <*> only here for the sake of privacy

Comment: `/etc/fstab` is a configuration file containing information about where your partitions and storage devices should be mounted and how.  The error message means that `/home/<user>/spc` is not in that file.

Comment: But it is possible to mount flash drives and tempfs without touching fstab file, however.  I guess I will have to update question somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sudo mount -t cifs //<server>/<share> -o username=user@domain,unc=\\\\<server>\\<share> /home/<user>/spc`

try

`sudo -S mount -t cifs //<server>/<share> /home/<user>/spc -o username=user@domain,unc=\\\\<server>\\<share>`

I don't know the `unc` option though.  I use for options username, password, iocharset, sec, file_mode, and dir_mode.

Answer (score 0):

For example: an SMB host named **ubuntu**.
In **/etc/samba/smb.conf** add the section at end of file:

```
[smbshare]
    path = /home/willem/smbshare
    read only = No
    valid users = willem
```

Set a password and restart the services:

```
$ sudo smbpasswd -a willem
$ sudo service smbd restart
$ sudo service nmbd restart
```

Give the host a minute to propagate its new settings.
In the SMB client:

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/willem/smbmount
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o user=willem //ubuntu.local/smbshare /media/willem/smbmount
Password for willem@//ubuntu.local/smbshare:  **********
$ ls -l /media/willem/smbmount/
total 4
-rw-r--r--+ 1 willem willem 29 mei  4 16:16 Date.txt
$ date > /media/willem/smbmount/Date2.txt
$ ls -l /media/willem/smbmount/
total 8
-rw-r--r--+ 1 willem willem 29 mei  4 18:12 Date2.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 willem willem 29 mei  4 16:16 Date.txt
```

Cleanup

```
$ sudo umount /media/willem/smbmount
$ sudo rmdir  /media/willem/smbmount
```